# How do I configure Vim to capture PC_Lint's output

Tags: vim, lint

I am running Vim on a Windows box and I would like to integrate my use of pc_lint into Vim.  I have figured out how to run lint from within Vim, however I don't know how to grab the output into Vim and ideally how to parse the output so that I can jump to the correct code lines via the error messages.

Does anyone know of a plug-in that will do this?  I couldn't find one.

Any advice for this Vim novice?

Cheers,
Andrew

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want the `:redir` command.

See this link for a good description: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_ex_command_output

Actually, here's a much easier way:

`:r ! command`

That will read the results of command into the current buffer.

Comment: Thanks that gets me part of the way there.  I have the output in a buffer, anyway to have vim intelligently parse the errors so I can jump to the corresponding lines of code causing the errors.

Comment: What you want is vim's quickfix.  Here's the link.  I have this set up with php's lint to do exactly what you're talking about.  http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html

Answer (score 3):

OK I got it working.

My efm setting wasn't working correctly.

In my pc_lint config file I have the following setting:

```
-"format=%(%f %l %C %) %t %n: %m"
```

And in my vimrc file I have the following setting:

```
set efm=%f\ \ %l\ \ %c\ \ %m
```

I also have the following script in my vimrc

```
" map f4 to run lint

map <f4> :call LintProject()<cr>

"use windows default shell

set shell=cmd.exe

function! LintProject()

    new "open a new buffer

    exec 'silent r! lint-nt c:\lint\vim\std.lnt *.c -b'

    exe "normal ggdd"  "remove blank line at the top of the file

    caddb "add content of the buffer to the quickfix window

    close "close the buffer

    copen "open quickfix window

endfunction
```

Now I can move around the quickfix window as normal and when I press enter I am taken to the file with the error.

Fantastic!!!